# F-test with plm-model

Tags: r, plm

I want to make a f-test to a plm-model and test for

```
model <- plm(y ~ a + b)
```

if

```
# a = b
```

and

```
# a = 0 and b = 0
```

I tried linearHypothesis like this

```
linearHypothesis(ur.model, c("a", "b")) to test for a = 0 and b = 0
```

but got the error

```
Error in constants(lhs, cnames_symb) : 
  The hypothesis "sgp1" is not well formed: contains bad coefficient/variable names.
Calls: linearHypothesis ... makeHypothesis -> rbind -> Recall -> makeHypothesis -> constants
In addition: Warning message:
In constants(lhs, cnames_symb) : NAs introduced by coercion
Execution halted
```

My example above is with code that is a little simplified if the problem is easy. If the problems is in the details is the actual code here.

```
model3 <- formula(balance.agr ~ sgp1 + sgp2 + cp + eu + election + gdpchange.imf + ue.ameco)
ur.model<-plm(model3, data=panel.l.fullsample, index=c("country","year"), model="within", effect="twoways")
linearHypothesis(ur.model, c("sgp1", "sgp2"), vcov.=vcovHC(plmmodel1, method="arellano", type = "HC1", clustering="group"))
```

Comment: if you provide your own code, make sure we have a dataset to try it on. Please provide a reproducible example next time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your error with one of the inbuilt data sets, even after quite a bit of fiddling.

Does this work for you?

```
require(plm)
require(car)
data(Grunfeld)
form <- formula(inv ~ value + capital)
re <- plm(form, data = Grunfeld, model = "within", effect = "twoways")
linearHypothesis(re, c("value", "capital"), 
                 vcov. = vcovHC(re, method="arellano", type = "HC1"))
```

Note also, that you seem to have an error in the more complex code you showed. You are using `linearHypothesis()` on the object `ur.model`, yet call `vcovHC()` on object `plmmodel1`. Not sure if that is the problem or not, but check that in case.

Is it possible to provide the data? Finally, edit your Question to include output from `sessionInfo()`. Mine is (from quite a busy R instance):

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.11.1 Patched (2010-08-25 r52803)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C             
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.utf8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C             LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.utf8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.utf8       LC_NAME=C                
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C           
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] splines   grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] car_2.0-2        nnet_7.3-1       plm_1.2-6        Formula_1.0-0   
 [5] kinship_1.1.0-23 lattice_0.19-11  nlme_3.1-96      survival_2.35-8 
 [9] mgcv_1.6-2       chron_2.3-37     MASS_7.3-7       vegan_1.17-4    
[13] lmtest_0.9-27    sandwich_2.2-6   zoo_1.6-4        moments_0.11    
[17] ggplot2_0.8.8    proto_0.3-8      reshape_0.8.3    plyr_1.2.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Matrix_0.999375-44 tools_2.11.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you are "mixing" models? You have a variance specification that starts out:

```
, ...vcov.=vcovHC(plmmodel1,
```

... and yet you are working with `ur.model`.